# this.formDef = undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have a function that calls api.send and returns an object with "res", but when I compare the result it says "undefined".

My function:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.api.send("Events", "getForm", { type: "events" })
            .then((res: any[]) => {
                this.formDef = res;
              this.optionsDict = [].concat
                    .apply([], this.formDef)
                    .filter((el) => !!el["options"])
                    .reduce((obj, el) => {
                        obj[el["field_key"]] = el["options"].reduce((o, e) => {
                            o[e["id"]] = e["name"];
                            return o;
                        }, {});
                        return obj;
                    }, {});
              });
}
```

My test:

```
let res = [[{ field_id: 66, field_key: "[[agents]]", field_label: "Agents", field_type: "select2", options: [{id: 1, name: 'Camilo'}, {id: 2, name: 'Monica'}]}],

let spy1 = spyOn(api, 'send').and.callFake(() => {
                return new Promise(function (resolve) {
                    resolve(res);
                });
            });

component.ngOnInit();

console.log(component.optionsDict); //this also appears undefined

expect(spy1).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.formDef).toEqual(res);
```

Comment: It would appear you are reading the `optionsDict` before it was even written to... I don't see you returning any promise from `ngOnInit` (nor `await`ing the call to it), so the next line where you read the value will execute immediately after the `ngOnInit` function returned, at which point the request was initiated and is in progress (not completed yet).

Comment: I have the solution thanks to your help, I found a way to solve it based on your answer, thank you very much. :D

Comment: @DavidAngarita As you have an answer you should answer your own question to help others out.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using fakeAsync and the fixture.detectChanges () and tick () methods, with this it waits for the promise to obtain a result and returns it for formDef.

I found the answer in this post: https://www.collegestash.com/testing-component-service-promise-angular-5/

This is the answer:

```
it('Should call api.send and return res', fakeAsync(() => {
    let res = [[{ 
                 field_id: 66, 
                 field_key: "[[agents]]", 
                 field_label: "Agents", 
                 field_type: "select2", 
                 options: [
                           {id: 1, name: 'Camilo'}, 
                           {id: 2, name: 'Monica'}
                          ]
               }]];
    let spy = spyOn(api, 'send').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(res));

    fixture.detectChanges();
    tick();
    component.ngOnInit();

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('Events', 'getForm', {type:'events'});
    expect(component.formDef).toEqual(res);
}));
```